# Finding all users that has visited

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, timestamp

Consider I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
UserID | Click | URL | Date
```

'UserID' is unique ID for each person. 'Click' is a unique ID for click on a page on a website. And then 'Date' is in format '2021-06-15 10:30:00 UTC'

What I want to find out is this:
"How many users have had two or more 'Clicks', where it was at least an hour between the users last visit"?

My only solution as of now is trying to extract hours some way using datetime library in python, and then counting users that fit the condition. I have not made it work.

How can this be done in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Sort by user ID and date.  Then it's easy to iterate the rows and check the interval since the last click.

Comment: What database/version is used?